# How can I set 'specific cell's background' in r shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, colors, background

I googled about my problem few days, but I coundn't find the way.
I should use shiny for reactive page, and my table should highlight specific cells.
I tried these methods.

1. background_color() in huxtable package isn't work at shiny.
2. DT or another packagies for table are column-based, so, It is difficult to choose a particular cell automatically.

So, I want to set specific cell's background like this:
[image]

How could I do?

```
ui <-dashboardPage(
  # App title ----
  dashboardHeader(title="1", titleWidth = 300),
  # Sidebar layout with a input and output definitions ----
  dashboardSidebar(width=300,
                   sidebarMenu(
                     textInput(inputId = "url", label = h4("Insert the URL:")))),

  # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
  dashboardBody(box(h4("Whole gnome"), div(tableOutput("wholegnome"))))))

server <-function(input, output) {
  # Return the requested dataset ----
  observeEvent(input$button, isolate({
    datasetInput <- eventReactive(input$button, {})
    output$wholegnome <- renderTable({
      data <- datasetInput()
      data0 <- unlist(strsplit(data, ""))
      tt<-rep(' ' , 50-length(data0)%%50)
      data0 <- c(data0, tt)
      data0<-matrix(data0, ncol=50, nrow=length(data0)%/%50, byrow=T, dimnames=list(num, c(1:50)))
})
```

Comment: Please provide sample code of your attempts

Comment: I added sample code!  Please check it.